# Making the list from 2 previous lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

Need advise how to make the third list from a couple of lists.
The first one is like this (about 20000 rows):
LIST1.

```
 field1 field2     field3       field4              field5 field6   field7
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1167  28669  001f.ce5d.cb4d  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.156    PTA  
    848  32350  c83a.350d.f368  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.601    PTA  
   1771  43465  c46e.1f7a.4763  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.959    PTA  
   1390  24116  dc9f.db01.c6e8  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.32     PTA  
    712  23579  d850.e6d5.cb1c  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.436    PTA  
   1239  28354  2828.5dd4.bc65  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.78     PTA  
    204  27816  e03f.491d.9978  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.341    PTA  
    383  28368  60e3.278c.7199  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.114    PTA  
    671  54657  c46e.1f81.a3d3  Gi0/0/1.10               1  Vi2.224    PTA
```

The second one is like this (about 20000 rows):
LIST2

```
 field1         field2          field3          field4      field5
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  Vi2.1        0001799            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.100.146.30
  Vi2.2        0010129            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.100.148.108
  Vi2.4        0010173            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.100.150.56
  Vi2.5        0011093            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.100.146.143
  Vi2.6        0003301            PPPoE        00:43:48 10.100.150.107
  Vi2.7        0010101            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.100.147.133
  Vi2.8        0001859            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.100.145.223
  Vi2.9        0010049            PPPoE        06:45:08 10.100.147.138
  Vi2.10       0003515            PPPoE        00:00:28 10.100.146.173
  Vi2.11       0001747            PPPoE        00:00:18 10.100.146.37
  Vi2.12       0011060            PPPoE        04:40:28 10.100.149.165
  Vi2.13       0001335            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.239.152.165
  Vi2.14       0010154            PPPoE        00:00:08 10.100.148.68
```

I need to create the third list, and the order is needed in such the way:

```
 field6(list1) Field2(list1) field3(list1) field2(list2) field5(list2)
```

By the way. Field6 from list1 is the same as field1 in list 2.
  I do understand, that I need to take every row from list1, make it a list of fields and after that take  the field 6 and go to list2 and search that value in the list2.
  And after that gather all needed fields into a new row. Anybody, I'm very,very new to parsing, please give me a couple of examples how to deal with this (I think typical) task!

Clarifying.
  I'm receiving that rows via python 3 telnetlib, like this:

```
import telnetlib

HOST = '2.22.22.22'
password = "user"
user = "user"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
tn.write(b"term len 0 \n")
tn.write(b"show pppoe session | exclude 7878.7878.7878 \n")

tn.write(b"\n exit\n")
mystring = tn.read_all().decode('ascii').replace('\r\n', '\n')
print(mystring)
temp_list = mystring.splitlines()
print(temp_list)
mylist  = ["\n".join(s for s in temp_list if 'PTA' in s and 'Vi2' in s)]
```

Comment: but this is not a python list -))

Comment: I'm receiving  that from the telnetlib from Cisco device.

Comment: what is the format of that tabular data?

Comment: It's a list of strings, every row is the string.

Comment: i mean is it text, csv or any other?

Comment: Hm... It's not the csv. It's the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You might want to hack numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/ab49be1d5a6f1a7c51298a8fe46a9f43bb2bb33b/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L748). `loadtxt` method loads tabular data from the text file and transforms it to array (not native python).

With this handy method, you can easily achieve the result.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t1 = "/home/ziya/Projects/python/test/list1.txt"
>>> t2 = "/home/ziya/Projects/python/test/list1.txt"
>>> d1 = np.loadtxt(t1, skiprows=2, dtype='str')
>>> d2 = np.loadtxt(t2, skiprows=2, dtype='str')
>>> d1_field1 = [i[0] for i in d1]
>>> d2_field1 = [i[1] for i in d1]
>>> d3_field1 = [i[2] for i in d1]
>>> d4_field2 = [i[3] for i in d2]
>>> d5_field2 = [i[4] for i in d2]
>>> d6_field2 = [i[5] for i in d2]
>>> new_list = []
>>> new_list.append(d1_field1)
>>> new_list.append(d2_field1)
>>> new_list.append(d3_field1)
>>> new_list.append(d4_field2)
>>> new_list.append(d5_field2)
>>> new_list.append(d6_field2)
>>> new_list
[['1167', '848', '1771', '1390', '712', '1239', '204', '383', '671'], ['28669', '32350', '43465', '24116', '23579', '28354', '27816', '28368', '54657'], ['001f.ce5d.cb4d', 'c83a.350d.f368', 'c46e.1f7a.4763', 'dc9f.db01.c6e8', 'd850.e6d5.cb1c', '2828.5dd4.bc65', 'e03f.491d.9978', '60e3.278c.7199', 'c46e.1f81.a3d3'], ['Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10', 'Gi0/0/1.10'], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['Vi2.156', 'Vi2.601', 'Vi2.959', 'Vi2.32', 'Vi2.436', 'Vi2.78', 'Vi2.341', 'Vi2.114', 'Vi2.224']]
 >>> np.array(new_list).transpose()
array([['1167', '28669', '001f.ce5d.cb4d', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.156'],
       ['848', '32350', 'c83a.350d.f368', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.601'],
       ['1771', '43465', 'c46e.1f7a.4763', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.959'],
       ['1390', '24116', 'dc9f.db01.c6e8', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.32'],
       ['712', '23579', 'd850.e6d5.cb1c', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.436'],
       ['1239', '28354', '2828.5dd4.bc65', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.78'],
       ['204', '27816', 'e03f.491d.9978', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.341'],
       ['383', '28368', '60e3.278c.7199', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.114'],
       ['671', '54657', 'c46e.1f81.a3d3', 'Gi0/0/1.10', '1', 'Vi2.224']], 
      dtype='|S14')
```